# Kontact crashes on startup

Tags: kubuntu, kde, akonadi, kontact, pim

Kontact seems to be a professional piece of software. Unfortunately it refuses to start.

How to reproduce:

1. Start Kontact (Flatpak)
2. Kontact loads but immediately crashes

Here is the output of the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=kontact org.kde.kontact
[2:25:0607/094916.717680:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(214)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Die Adresse wird bereits verwendet (98)
Trying to create ksycoca...
org.kde.pim.korganizer: Error occurred  "" "Unable to create persistent search"
org.kde.pim.korganizer: Error occurred  "" "Unable to create persistent search"
ASSERT: "mIncidences[type].value(uid) == incidence" in file /run/build-runtime/kcalendarcore/src/memorycalendar.cpp, line 324
*** KMail got signal 6 (Exiting)
*** Dead letters dumped.
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kontact path = /app/bin pid = 2
KCrash: Arguments: /app/bin/kontact
```

Flatpak info:
Kontact 5.23.1 via Flathub

system:
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620